# When using regular expressions in Clojure or Java, how can I use named capture groups?

Tags: java, regex, clojure

Since Java 7, named capture groups have been supported.  However, the built-in Clojure functions `re-matches`, `re-find`, and `re-groups` do not allow access to the capture groups by name.

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  ; Define a phone number pattern with some named capture groups.
  ; The reader literal #"..." allows us to avoid double-backslash like
  ; we'd need if using the form `(re-pattern <string>)`
  (let [patt #"(?<area>\d{3})-(?<prefix>\d{3})-(?<tail>\d{4})"]
    (is= java.util.regex.Pattern (type patt))

    ; `re-matches` will find the capture groups and stick them in a vector
    ; after the full match The capture groups are numbered starting with 1.
    ; The full match is like group zero.
    (is= ["619-239-5464" "619" "239" "5464"] (re-matches patt "619-239-5464"))

    ; Construct a java.util.regex.Matcher.  Keep in mind that it is a mutable object!
    (let [matcher (re-matcher patt "619-239-5464")]
      ; Execute the Matcher via `re-find`. It returns all 4 groups and caches them
      (is= ["619-239-5464" "619" "239" "5464"] (re-find matcher))

      ; `re-groups` simply returns the cached result from the Matcher
      (is= ["619-239-5464" "619" "239" "5464"] (re-groups matcher))
```

How can I use named capture groups in a regex from Clojure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25892277

Answer (score 3):

The class `java.util.regex.Matcher` supports named capture groups, but you need to use Java interop to get at them. An example:

```
; We need the instance function Matcher.group( <name> ) to extract named groups
(is= "619" (.group matcher "area"))
(is= "239" (.group matcher "prefix"))
(is= "5464" (.group matcher "tail"))))
```

The above code is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).