# Regular Expression named capturing groups support in Java 7

Tags: java, regex, java-7

Since Java 7 regular expressions API offers support for named capturing groups.
The method [java.util.regex.Matcher.group(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-java.lang.String-) returns the input subsequence captured by the given named-capturing group, but there's no example available on API documentations.

What is the right syntax to specify and retrieve a named capturing group in Java 7?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Specifying named capturing group

Use the following regex with a single capturing group as an example `([Pp]attern)`.

Below are 4 examples on how to specify a [named capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) for the regex above:

```
(?<Name>[Pp]attern)
(?<group1>[Pp]attern)
(?<name>[Pp]attern)
(?<NAME>[Pp]attern)
```

Note that the [name of the capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname) must strictly matches the following Pattern:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

The group name is case-sensitive, so you must specify the exact group name when you are referring to them (see below).

### Backreference the named capturing group in regex

To [back-reference the content matched by a named capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#backref) in the regex (correspond to 4 examples above):

```
\k<Name>
\k<group1>
\k<name>
\k<NAME>
```

The named capturing group is still numbered, so in all 4 examples, it can be back-referenced with `\1` as per normal.

### Refer to named capturing group in replacement string

To [refer to the capturing group in replacement string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) (correspond to 4 examples above):

```
${Name}
${group1}
${name}
${NAME}
```

Same as above, in all 4 examples, the content of the capturing group can be referred to with `$1` in the replacement string.

### Named capturing group in [COMMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) mode

Using `(?<name>[Pp]attern)` as an example for this section.

Oracle's implementation of the `COMMENT` mode (embedded flag `(?x)`) parses the following examples to be identical to the regex above:

```
(?x)  (  ?<name>             [Pp] attern  )
(?x)  (  ?<  name  >         [Pp] attern  )
(?x)  (  ?<  n  a m    e  >  [Pp] attern  )
```

Except for `?<` which must **not** be separated, it allows arbitrary spacing even in between the name of the capturing group.

### Same name for different capturing groups?

While it is possible in .NET, Perl and PCRE to define the same name for different capturing groups, it is currently **not supported** in Java (Java 8). You can't use the same name for different capturing groups.

### Named capturing group related APIs

New methods in Matcher class to support retrieving captured text by group name:

- [`group(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29) (from Java 7)
- [`start(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start-java.lang.String-) (from **Java 8**)
- [`end(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end-java.lang.String-) (from **Java 8**)

The corresponding method is missing from [`MatchResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#start-int-) class as of Java 8. There is an on-going [Enhancement request JDK-8065554](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065554) for this issue.

There is currently no API to get the list of named capturing groups in the regex. [We have to jump through extra hoops to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588903/get-group-names-in-java-regex). Though it is quite useless for most purposes, except for writing a regex tester.

Answer (score 4):

The new syntax for a named capturing group is `(?<name>X)` for a matching group X named by "name". The following code captures the regex (\w+) (any group of alphanumeric characters). To name this capturing group you must add the expression ? inside the parentheses just before the regex to be captured.

```
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(?<teste>\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("The first word is a match");
matcher.find();
String myNamedGroup= matcher.group("teste");
System.out.printf("This is yout named group: %s", myNamedGroup);
```

This code returns prints the following output:

> This is your named group: The

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-