# How to get the names of the regex named capturing group in a match in Java?

Tags: java, regex, scala

Given:

```
String text = "FACEBOOK is buying GOOGLE and FACE BOOK";
```

and:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<FB>(FACE(\\p{Space}?)BOOK))|(?<GOOGL>(GOOGL(E)?))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Group=FB matches substring="FACEBOOK" at position=[0, 8)
Group=GOOGL matches substring="GOOGLE" at position=[19, 25)
Group=FB matches substring="FACE BOOK" at position=[30, 39)
```

However, I have been unable to get the group name. Here is my attempt in Scala:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
  val pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<FB>(FACE(\\p{Space}?)BOOK))|(?<GOOGL>(GOOGL(E)?))")
  val text = "FACEBOOK is buying GOOGLE and FACE BOOK"
  val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)

  while(matcher.find()) {
    println(s"Group=???? matches substring=${matcher.group()} at position=[${matcher.start},${matcher.end})")
  }
```

EDIT:
Someone marked this as a duplicate of [Get group names in java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588903/get-group-names-in-java-regex) but this is a different question. This is asking given a MATCH, how to find the group name. The other question is asking how to get the group-name to String (or index) given a Pattern object.

Comment: Fwiw, in [this little library](https://github.com/travisbrown/expressier) I have a parser for patterns since I needed access to names (among other things).

Comment: @Tunaki: I provided explanation why this is not a duplicate of the question you marked as.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Thanks for the link. Can you give a sketch of how you achieved the named group extraction?

Comment: The linked question is also asking how to find the group name for a match, exactly like your question. In that linked question, they could only get the matched value and their index; and they want the name, like you. In order to find a group, you need to match. In fact, the top answer even bolds *from the match*.

Comment: @Tunaki: If you look at the answers for that question - it is answering how to get a Map from group-name to pattern string given a regex. I am asking, given a Match, I need to know the group name.

Comment: It is not answering that. It is answering the question (and what is also your question) which is "how to get the group name from a captured group". And the answer show how to do that in an example with a map from the name of the capturing group to the captured value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt in Scala:

```
import java.util.regex.{MatchResult, Pattern}

class GroupNamedRegex(pattern: Pattern, namedGroups: Set[String]) {
  def this(regex: String) = this(Pattern.compile(regex), 
    "\\(\\?<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)>".r.findAllMatchIn(regex).map(_.group(1)).toSet)

  def findNamedMatches(s: String): Iterator[GroupNamedRegex.Match] = new Iterator[GroupNamedRegex.Match] {
    private[this] val m = pattern.matcher(s)
    private[this] var _hasNext = m.find()

    override def hasNext = _hasNext

    override def next() = {
      val ans = GroupNamedRegex.Match(m.toMatchResult, namedGroups.find(group => m.group(group) != null))
      _hasNext = m.find()
      ans
    }
  }
}

object GroupNamedRegex extends App {
  case class Match(result: MatchResult, groupName: Option[String])

  val r = new GroupNamedRegex("(?<FB>(FACE(\\p{Space}?)BOOK))|(?<GOOGL>(GOOGL(E)?))")
  println(r.findNamedMatches("FACEBOOK is buying GOOGLE and FACE BOOK FB").map(s => s.groupName -> s.result.group()).toList)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [named-regexp](http://tony19.github.io/named-regexp/) Java library. It is a thin wrapper around `java.util.regex` with named capture groups support, primarily for pre-Java-7 users, but it also contains the methods to inspect the group names (which appears to be missing even from Java 11):

- [Pattern#groupNames](http://tony19.github.io/named-regexp/doc/0.2.5/com/google/code/regexp/Pattern.html#groupNames())
- [Matcher#namedGroups](http://tony19.github.io/named-regexp/doc/0.2.5/com/google/code/regexp/Matcher.html#namedGroups%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Java 20 is adding the [`namedGroups`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#namedGroups()) method to `MatchResult` (which [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) implements).  This can be used to get the current match group name in your example.

Here is a Java implementation:

```java
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Group=%s matches substring=%s at position=[%s,%s)%n",
            getCurrentGroupName(matcher), 
            matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
}
```

```java
private static String getCurrentGroupName(Matcher matcher) {
    return matcher.namedGroups().keySet().stream()
            .filter(n -> matcher.group(n) != null)
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```