# Java: how to extract and populate values to a Map from a String based on a provided pattern?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2 Strings, one is pattern that contains parameters and the other is title.

I would like to extract parameter values from the title and store them to a Map based on the provided pattern. The parameters in the pattern are prefixed with a $.

Example 1:

```
pattern = "home/$service/$source-$metadataId"
title = "home/serviceA/test-ABC"
```

then the output should be a map that has all the following key value pairs:

```
service = serviceA
source = test
metadataId = ABC
```

Example 2:

```
pattern = "home/$service/$source/$region/$year/$month/$day-$metadataId"
title = "home/serviceA/test/NA/2019/3/3-ABC"
```

then the output should be a map that has all the following key value pairs:

```
service = serviceA
source = test
region = NA
year = 2019
month = 3
day = 3
metadataId = ABC
```

Please let me know whether there is any library that can do this in Java or how would you achieve it in plain Java.

Note:

1. The parameter names don't contain any special characters. (eg:
   punctuations)
2. All the parameter names start with a $

Comment: I am not aware of a library that can parse info like this. Probably you will have to parse it manually.

Comment: Better drop the first request about recommending a library. Such questions are fully off topic here. And I am not aware of existing solutions to this problem. For "how to solve" it, that depends on the *real* nature of your "patterns". Meaning: two examples are nice, but you probably need a parser, and an engine that takes your "patterns" and applies them to text input. You better start by clearly defining the exact nature of these patterns.

Comment: So by "don't contain any special characters" you mean the parameter names only contain ASCII letters and number?

Comment: We see only your requirements, it would be nice to have your attempt (a code snippet) as well.

Comment: @markspace you can take it as it only contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question? If so, please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No library that I know of. This problem is very specific to certain cases. But you can write your own library that handles more cases like that. Here is a little program in Java that will work for all the cases you described (can be further extended). Hopefully it gives you some idea.

```
    String pattern = "home/$service/aaa/$source-$metadataId";
    String title = "home/serviceA/aaa/test-ABC";

    String patternNew = pattern.replaceAll("/\\$|-\\$", "/");

    // assuming both the strings contain same number of tokens.
    String[] keyTokens = (patternNew).split("/|-");
    String[] valueTokens = (title).split("/|-");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int n = 1; n < keyTokens.length; n++) {
        String key = (keyTokens[n]);
        String value = (valueTokens[n]);

        if(key.equals(value))
            continue;

        map.put(key, value);
    }

    for (String name : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(" = " + map.get(name));
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: It cannot handle this case: pattern = "home/$service/aaa/$source-$metadataId" and title = "home/serviceA/aaa/test-ABC"

Comment: Its because in this input, the pattern aaa does not start with $. In the question you stated (2. All the parameter names start with a $). According to your statement it should be $aaa or something

Comment: aaa is not a parameter, which is the same as home. It's just a regular string literal in between the parameters

Comment: So you want it to handle "aaa" by skipping it?  And skip the "aaa" string in the value too?

Comment: I see. This was a bit unclear from your question. I updated my code. Should work now. Unless there is another ambiguous case. Regardless, I suggest maybe adding more details to the question(More examples). It can be an interesting use case for future readers. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Alex Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: Your solution mostly look good except I found that you are assuming the parameter name and value are not the same. For example, if pattern = "home/$service/aaa/$source-$metadataId" and title = "home/service/aaa/test-ABC" then since $service has a value that is service, it won't be included in the result. @Sibgha

Comment: I certainly believe you must accept one of the answers on this post even if it did not quite provide you the code that you can use exactly without adjusting or extending further. The answers are to give you a direction and most importantly address your confusion which I believe you nearly got. If an answer does not work for a specific input, you can always extend the code like I mentioned in my answer. The important thing to take out of it is regex formation that matches the pattern of your string. And in the answers are many ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] p = pattern.split("/\\$|-");
String[] t = titlesplit("/|-");

 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
 for(int i=1; i<t.length; i++){
       map.put(p[i], t[i]);
  }
```

Comment: This is pretty close to correct I think, for "plain Java."  I think though you have to skip the "home" string, and that means checking to see if your parameters start with a "$", which is mentioned in the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use regular expression similar to `\$(\w+)` to split pattern into literal chunks and placeholder names.  For the first example you will get the following literal chunks: `"home/"`, `"/"`, `"-"`, `""` (last chunk is empty string), and the following placeholder names: `"service"`, `"source"`, `"metadataId"`.
2. Now you construct regular expression from literal chunks like this: `home/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)`.  Do not forget to properly quote literal chunks.
3. Apply this regular expression and get values of captured groups: `"serviceA"`, `"test"`, `"ABC"`.
4. Combine into map placeholder names collected at step 1 with capturing groups values obtained at step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the parameter *values* (not just names) can only contain word characters, you can do this:

```
String pattern = "home/$service/$source/$region/$year/$month/$day-$metadataId";
String title = "home/serviceA/test/NA/2019/3/3-ABC";
String regex = "\\Q" + pattern.replaceAll("\\$(\\w+)", "\\\\E(?<$1>\\\\w+)\\\\Q") + "\\E";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(title);
if (m.find()) {
    Map<String, String> map = getNamedGroupCandidates(regex).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), m::group));
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

where `getNamedGroupCandidates` is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588989/5133585):

```
private static Set<String> getNamedGroupCandidates(String regex) {
    Set<String> namedGroups = new TreeSet<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(\\?<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)>").matcher(regex);

    while (m.find()) {
        namedGroups.add(m.group(1));
    }

    return namedGroups;
}
```

I basically convert your "pattern" into a regex with named groups. I then get all the group names and use them to get the captured values. And finally I put all these into a single map.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pattern = br.readLine();
        String title = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(parseString(pattern,title).toString());
    }   

    private static Map<String,String> parseString(String pattern,String title){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        String[] pat_tokens = pattern.split("/");
        String[] title_tokens = title.split("/");;

        for(int i=0;i<pat_tokens.length;++i){
            String[] sub_tokens = pat_tokens[i].split("\\-");
            String[] title_sub_tokens = title_tokens[i].split("\\-");
            for(int j=0;j<sub_tokens.length;++j){
                if(sub_tokens[j].charAt(0) != '$') continue;
                map.put(sub_tokens[j],title_sub_tokens[j]);
            }
        }       

        return map;
    }
}
```

Well, you can just split the string based on `/` and on `-` for individual tokens. if the starting character of a string is not `$`, then it isn't a key you would like to have it in your map.

Comment: I updated the code with a fix. If you don't like the `$` in your key name, you can just use substring() to get rid of it.