# What is replacement of "match.groupdict()" method of python in Java?

Tags: java, python, regex, code-conversion

I have python code as below. I want to convert this code in Java but I am not getting replacement of `match.groupdict()` in Java. I have applied two different regex for each `matchRegex(expr, data)` method call in examples below but there may be more regex for every call also. Here is my code:

Python code:

```
import re

def matchRegex(expr, data):
  match = re.compile(expr).match(data)
  stmt = match.groupdict()
  print("matchRegex() Output = ",stmt)


matchRegex(r'R(?P<rcount>[0-9]*)X?(?P<xdelta>[+\-]?\d*\.?\d*)?Y?(?P<ydelta>[+\-]?\d*\.?\d*)?', "R0004X015Y32")
matchRegex(r'(?P<deprecated>(G54)|(G55))?D(?P<d>\d+)\*', "D10*")
```

Python Output:

```
matchRegex() Output =  {'rcount': '0004', 'xdelta': '015', 'ydelta': '32'}
matchRegex() Output  =  {'deprecated': None, 'd': '10'}
```

My Java Effort :

```
public Map<String, String> matchRegex(Pattern expr, String data) {
    Matcher match = expr.matcher(data);
    if (match == null) {
        return new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    }else {
        /*
         Dont know how to implement replacement of "stmt = match.groupdict()"            
         */
    }
```

Comment: It seems impossible to do directly in Java. Do you consider _functional_ maps/dictionaries? `UnaryOperator<String> = matcher::group` will transform a group name to a matching result for that group.

Comment: There could be simpler solution if I understood correctly. If regex patterns are different on every call then you first have to figure out how many different patterns are there. Once you have all the patterns then it can be used in a simple switch case code.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588903/get-group-names-in-java-regex

Comment: jdk open ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7032377