# how to extract variables based on a pattern braces using regex in Java?

Tags: java, text

Have this data input:

pattern: `anyValue{variable1}otherValue{variable2}lastValue`

value: `anyValuehellootherValueworldlastValue`

Expect this output

```
variable1: hello
variable2: world
```

can i have any variables with braces,
I would like an example using Regex with an implementation in Java or another language,

Comment: var values = input.split("anyValue");` should get you most of the way there.

Comment: the values between variables can be anything and do not necessarily have a pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in java:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern= "anyvalue{variable1}anyvalue{variable2}anyvalue{var3}";
        String input = "anyvaluehelloanyvalueworldanyvaluesomething";

        // Convert the pattern into a regular expression
        String regex = pattern.replaceAll("\\{(.+?)\\}", "(?<$1>.*)");

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
        
        if (m.find()) {
            // Get the names of the capture groups from the pattern
            Pattern groupNamesPattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\?<(.+?)>");
            Matcher groupNamesMatcher = groupNamesPattern.matcher(regex);
            
            // Print all the variables that were found
            while (groupNamesMatcher.find()) {
                String variableName = groupNamesMatcher.group(1);
                String variableValue = m.group(variableName);
                System.out.println(variableName + ": " + variableValue);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match found.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am basically converting your pattern to named groups for any {variable_name} in the pattern. As far as I know, there is no easy way to get the groups' names, so you need a second regex to get those for your output.

However, there seem to be a few alternatives to find the named groups. You can follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588903/get-group-names-in-java-regex) if you want to look into other alternatives to find the names of the groups.

Comment: this input:
String pattern = "test{variable1}.{variable2}";
String input = "testvalue1.value2";
should returns: 
variable1: value1
variable2: value2
but returns:
variable1: value1.value
variable2:

Comment: and:
 String pattern = "test{variable1}.{variable2}";
 String input = "testval.ue1.value2";
should returns:
variable1: val.ue1 
variable2: value2